# Progress bar goes past 100

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a progress bar in on one of my web pages. My problem with this progress bar is that if the background process takes a bit longer than expected, it will keep going and move beyond 100 percent and even out of the frame.

I use elements in a file to check and see if each criteria for the progress bar is available and then update the progress accordingly. This all works well, but no matter what I do, I still can't tell the progress bar to stop moving past 100 percent. I'm new to this of course. 
Can you please help me figure this out? I've been trying to fix it for hours.

This just FYI: The back-end is written using Django and python.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function grabber() {
        elem = document.getElementById("progress_bar_inner");
        width = 1;
        interval = setInterval(ajaxcall, 400);
        var i;
        finished = [];
        addition = 0.3;
    });
    var ajaxcall = function getstatus () {
        $("#progressText").text((width).toFixed(1) + '%');
        $("#progress_bar_inner:after").css('content' , width+'%');
        if (width >= 80 && finished.length <= 8){
            //alert('condition triggered')
            addition = 0.15;
        }
        width+=addition;
        elem.style.width = width + '%';
        $.getJSON("/some-address/status/{{some-id}}", function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            for (var i in data){
                if(data[i]){
                console.log(i);
                if (!finished.includes(i)){
                    $('#'+i).addClass('active');
                    finished.push(i);
                    //console.log(finished);
                    if (width < finished.length/10*100){
                    width = finished.length/10*100;
                    }
                    if (finished.length === 10){
                    //alert('se finiiiiiiiiiiii');
                    width = 100;
                    elem.style.width = '%'+width;
                    $("#progress_bar_inner:after").css('content' , '%'+width);
                    $("#progressText").text('%'+(width).toFixed(1));
                    console.log(data);
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    window.location.replace("{% url "go-to-result-page" some-id %}");
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't this  line `$("#progress_bar_inner:after").css('content' , '%'+width);` be `$("#progress_bar_inner:after").css('content' , width+'%');`

Comment: Yes. But that did not solve the issue. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Use `max-width:100%` and for text before setting check `width>100 if reset to 100`

Comment: Could you do me a favor and send this as an answer? I would very much appreciate it if you edit my code snippet. I have very little experience with JavaScript.